# opengl 2d game only drawing second sprite texture and not first

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics2d

I'm currently creating a 2d fighting game utilizing OpenGL and I have run into a problem where OpenGL is only drawing at my last initialized sprite position, regardless of how many sprites I initialize and try and draw. Even when I initialize a `sprite1` and `sprite2` but only draw `sprite1`, `sprite` is what will still be drawn. It starts with my sprite class where I initialize where on the screen I want my image as well as what image to use:

Sprite.cpp

```
 Init(int screenCoordinateX, int screenCoordinateY, uint imageWidth, unsigned int imageHeight, std::string imageFilePath)
{
    //casting to float since GLSL shader variables vec2,3,4 require vertex data to be in floats
    this->x = static_cast<float>(x);
    this->y = static_cast<float>(y);
    this->width = static_cast<float>(width);
    this->height = static_cast<float>(height);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);

    Blz::Graphics::GLTexture texture(imageFilePath);
    this->texture = texture;

    float halfWidth = this->width / 2;

    //Setting sprite origin at bottom middle of image by subtracting half width 
    this->vertexData.at(0).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x + (this->width - halfWidth), this->y + this->height, 0.0f });//Top right corner
    this->vertexData.at(1).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x - halfWidth, this->y + height, 0.0f });//Top left corner
    this->vertexData.at(2).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x - halfWidth, this->y, 0.0f });//Bottom left corner
    this->vertexData.at(3).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x - halfWidth, this->y, 0.0f });//Bottom left corner
    this->vertexData.at(4).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x + (this->width - halfWidth), this->y, 0.0f });//Bottom right corner
    this->vertexData.at(5).SetPosition(glm::vec3{ this->x + (this->width - halfWidth), this->y + this->height, 0.0f });//Top right corner

    this->vertexData.at(0).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 1.0f, 1.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(1).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 0.0f, 1.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(2).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 0.0f, 0.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(3).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 0.0f, 0.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(4).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 1.0f, 0.0f });
    this->vertexData.at(5).SetUV(glm::vec2{ 1.0f, 1.0f });

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (sizeof(Vector3D) * this->vertexData.size()), &this->vertexData.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3D), (void*)offsetof(Vector3D, position));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3D), (void*)offsetof(Vector3D, textureCoordinates));

    //Unbind 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I then try and render sprites passed in to renderer like so:

Renderer.cpp

```
void Renderer::Draw(Sprite& sprite)
{
    glm::mat4 orthoProjection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<sfloat>(1024), 0.0f, static_cast<sfloat>(768));
    GLuint transformationMatrixUniformLocation = this->shaderProgram.GetUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformationMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &(orthoProjection[0][0]));

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sprite.texture.id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sprite.vboID);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I here is my main.cpp where I begin to call everything:

```
int main() 
{
    Blz::Graphics::Renderer renderer;
    Blz::Window window;
    Blz::Input input;
    Scene scene;

    window.Initialize();
    renderer.Init();

    Sprite sprite1;
    sprite.Init(900, 300, 200, 200, "CharImage.png");

    Sprite sprite2;
    sprite2.Init(100, 100, 200, 200, "CharImage.png");

    while (!input.IsKeyPressed(SDLK_ESCAPE))
    {
        window.ClearBuffers();

        renderer.Draw(sprite1);

        window.SwapBuffers();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So even though I ask for `sprite1` to be drawn, only `sprite2`'s position at 100x 100y gets drawn to the screen. Even if I manually try and enter a `vboID` of 1 (which is the `vboID` of `sprite1`) within renderer.cpp, it still draws `sprite2`'s position. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my Shaders if necessary:

VertexShader.glsl

```
#version 430

in vec3 vertexPosition;
in vec2 textCoord;

out vec2 TextureCoord;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = transformationMatrix * position;
    TextureCoord = textCoord;
};
```

FragmentShader.glsl

```
#version 430

out vec4 daColor;
in vec2 TextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D basicTexture;

void main()
{
    vec4 texel = texture(basicTexture, TextureCoord);
    daColor = texel;
};
```

Comment: Please clarify if you are using OpenGL or OpenGL ES and edit tags accordingly.

Comment: @Reaper Sorry, I took off openGL ES. It's openGL

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh sorry. I new I would forget to post something. It's set inside my Renderer::Init() function which is called prior  `GLuint uniformLocation = this->shaderProgram.GetUniformLocation("basicTexture");` and set with  `glUniform1i(uniformLocation, 0)`

Comment: @Rabbid76 and I'm using a vector 3D instead of 2D because I'm not sure if I would need the z value later for some kind of ordering technique (this is my first attempt at a game so kinda learning as I go).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes. It seems to only ever draw the last sprite texture specified

Comment: @Rabbid76 Haha, ya. I just try and decide what code is the most useful for people look at without making my post unwieldly.

Comment: @Rabbid76 They are set in main like this `Fighter* player1 = scene.CreateFighter("CharImage.png", 100, 0);` `Fighter* player1 = scene.CreateFighter("CharImage.png", 900, 0);` Which eventually calls Sprite Init func

Comment: It should be. I only call glActiveTexture once and its inside the GLTexture constructor. I never disable the active texture or anything as far as I know

Comment: I mean heres my github account with the game - https://github.com/boagz57/ShadowGods  . Should be able to download it and run it on windows with visual studio if that helps or at least see what other code I have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150476/discussion-between-jason-and-rabbid76).

Comment: You shouldn't be adding your `(x, y)` to position your model. Instead, use a transformation matrix to do the translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess this is a lesson for anyone aspiring to learn and use OpenGL. Anytime you are using VBOs and vbo ids to bind an OpenGL buffer to you also need to again specify your vertexattribpointers before drawing. So my new renderer.cpp file looks like this:

```
void Renderer::Draw(Sprite& sprite)
{
    glm::mat4 orthoProjection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<sfloat>(1024), 0.0f, static_cast<sfloat>(768));
    GLuint transformationMatrixUniformLocation = this->shaderProgram.GetUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformationMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &(orthoProjection[0][0]));

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sprite.texture.id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sprite.vboID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3D), (void*)offsetof(Vector3D, position));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3D), (void*)offsetof(Vector3D, textureCoordinates));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

This other SO answer gives a reason as to why: [is VertexAttribPointer needed after each BindBuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665671/is-vertexattribpointer-needed-after-each-bindbuffer). To avoid this, you would use the newer VAO's which store vertex attribute info so you don't have to specify vertexattribpointer functions everytime.